# "Dove in slow motion"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Could you please help me to find out the meaning of this phrase?
(dove in slow motion)

> I wrote 90 pages over 72 hours, pulling not one but two all-nighters, sprinted across campus, *dove in slow motion*, and got it in just at the deadline.

Comment: In American English, _dove_ is the past of _dive_ (not in British). I guess this refers to the practice of sports coverage where a crucial moment is replayed in slow motion.

Answer (score 1):

Dove (variant past tense of 'dive') is considered by many to be mainly American, but it is creeping into British English.

> "OED’s first citation is from 1855, in Henry Wadsworth Longfellow’s
> Song of Hiawatha: ‘Straight into the river Kwasind Plunged as if he
> were an otter, Dove as if he were a beaver.’ In later editions Dove
> became Dived, perhaps under editorial influence."

As Colin Fine says, the 'slow motion' part is probably intended to evoke the slow-motion replay of crucial moments in TV sports coverage.

[Macmillan Dictionary Blog](https://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/a-quick-dive-into-dived-vs-dove)

Historically, within the US, dived/dove used to be something of a dialect marker.

> E. Bagby Atwood’s 1953 study A Survey of Verb Forms in the Eastern
> United States found that dove was chiefly Northeastern, used as the
> dominant form in New England, Upstate New York, and the Northeast
> corridor as far south as Wilmington, Delaware. In Central
> Pennsylvania, northeast Maryland, lowland areas of South Carolina, and
> a few other pockets, dived and dove were relatively interchangeable.
> Elsewhere in the Eastern US, presumably, dived was typical, along with
> more unusual forms like div and duv.

[Dived vs. Dove in American Dialects](http://dialectblog.com/2013/04/11/dived-dove-american-dialects/)

Comment: I think the slow motion is less about sports than it is about slow motion being used for dramatic effect in movies or TV shows. There's a [TV tropes entry](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Overcrank) about it.